# Sorting efficiently with 90% in 1 to 100

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Given an array of 10000 integers, with 90% are among 1 to 100, and the others are between 101­ and 10000, how to sort efficiently?

Comment: And what is the issue with traditional algorithms such as quicksort or merge sort?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Quicksort has the *&Omega;(n log(n))* lower bound on comparison-based sorting, whereas the question indicates that most of the elements can be sorted with counting sort, which does not have this lower bound. So, in principle, it *can* be made faster than counting sort (whether this will happen in practice is another matter).

Comment: @AmiTavory "So, in principle, it can be made faster than counting sort": how ?

Comment: Typo - faster than *quicksort*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of elements `N` equals their range (`1` to `N`) so it is harmless to use counting sort on the whole range. This is `Θ(N)`.